# cross validation of past data

Tags: cross-validation

I have time-series data. from 2012-today
doing the regular CV and nested cv
I have unseen data from 2010-2011.
is there any good paper on how can I use the unseen data from 2010-2011 for testing?

Comment: You could do a walk forward validation.  If you have 10 years worth of data, you could train on 5, use 3 of the remaining 5 as a validation set, and the remaining 2 as a test set.  I'm just making those numbers up, but the scheme remains the same.

Comment: this is regular CV, I am looking to something more "unexpected" and that's why I want to start the train on year 3-9, validate on 10 and test on 1-2